# flow require object to have one of propperty

Tags: javascript, flowtype

i have an object that should eathher contain a key called `school` or a key called `company`, i would like not to "just" mark them both as optional but say "one or the other".

i have tryed the following:

```
type schoolType = {
    id: string,
    name: string
}
type companyType = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
}
type place = {
   start: Date,
   end: Date,
   (company|school): companyType | schoolType
}
```

changing the keyname is not possible as the object is comming from the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Given what you said in the comments below, the better solution would be to just do:

```
type place = {
   start: Date,
   end: Date,
   company?: companyType,
   school?: schoolType
}
```

because you're never sure if it has the school type or the company type. You could later cast it to its actual type once you figure out what that is.

---

You can do it like this [(try)](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAzgxgCwPZIDYBVzQLxQN4BQUxUAlgCYBcswATqQHYDmANESQwIYC2E1MdRkwIBfAqEhQ4SbmE4MQmSbkIkyVGvWZs1XXv0HbRBcVihhUnODnzsBnWsGoARTsAg6oEBhtfu2YqaSFlYQAOqkwAgAwjJyClAq7FAAdGkh1p7SsvIg1NnxiljGQdAZ4ZEIAMqIKKiJtsRpKeWe8Mho-LVoShAlEmWW1jAN5RFRsTkJAD7mQxVRNR2oJtIMArDdqNTlI0nE9o7UDBAA7lB+EAAUAJSe3hon55e3bVvUqiQU1ABEAIw-TzEPR8KA-ABMP3YYkCaw2BVyO3me0aNAcTigTwubmud3YD2OZ2x7le7ARCg+yXUvwBQMxPFBEKhxBhQA)

```
type schoolType = {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

type companyType = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
}

type place = {
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
}

type placeWithCompany = {
   ...place,
  company: companyType
}

type placeWithSchool = {
  ...place,
  school: schoolType
}

type places = placeWithCompany | placeWithSchool

const school: places = {
  start: new Date(),
  end: new Date(),
  school: {
    id: "1",
    name: "2"
  }
}

const company: places = {
  start: new Date(),
  end: new Date(),
  company: {
    id: "1",
    name: "2"
  }
}
```

The `...place` is just to save some typing. It works exactly the same as object spread if you're not familiar.

Though maybe there's no point because `schoolType` and `companyType` are identical, and thus you could just not differentiate between the two.

Comment: it sort of works. but the flow checker stil complains if a do somthing like: `const a = place.school ? place.school.id : place.company.id` it says `Cannot get "place.company.id" because property "id" is missing in property "company" of unknown type`

Comment: @VeXii hmm weird. Let me play around with that and get back to you.

Comment: thanks, where realy hopping i did'nt have to do this also becouse i still have to do an dubble check to satisfy the flow checker